# Three movie adaptations

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, movies

The following table is about three different movies which were adapted from three novels.

[image: grid of movies (1,2 and 3) vs role (lead actor and author of original novel.]

---

Clues:

1. X and Y are siblings.
2. All three movie titles have a particular word in common.

---

***Identify the authors A, B and C.***
***Identify the siblings X and Y.***

Comment: Movie 2 and Movie 3 seem to be entirely interchangeable - is there a particular ordering you were hoping for, to disambiguate this puzzle?

Comment: @Stiv Actually, no. I thought of revealing either an author B or C at first but decided against it to make the puzzle as enigmatic as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Movie 1

> **Gone with the Wind**, based on the book by Margaret Mitchell, starring Clark Gable (pictured).

Movie 2

> **Gone Girl**, based on a book by Gillian Flynn, starring Ben Affleck.

Movie 3

> **Gone Baby Gone**, based on a book by Dennis Lehane, starring Casey Affleck.

X and Y are siblings.

> Ben and Casey Affleck are brothers.

All three movie titles have a particular word in common.

> "Gone".

Comment: Was actually about to post, thinking: 'wow, I got an answer finally' before i realised you posted. Nice.

Comment: @Stevo I know the feeling hehe